# How do I translate this kurtosis formula from java documentation to Ruby?

Tags: java, ruby, statistics

I have a problem with the strange formula for kurtosis used in java documentation:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math//javadocs/api-3.0/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/moment/Kurtosis.html

```
Computes the Kurtosis of the available values.

We use the following (unbiased) formula to define kurtosis:

kurtosis = { [n(n+1) / (n -1)(n - 2)(n-3)] sum[(x_i - mean)^4] / std^4 } - [3(n-1)^2 / (n-2)(n-3)]

where n is the number of values, mean is the Mean and std is the StandardDeviation

Note that this statistic is undefined for n < 4. Double.Nan is returned when there is not sufficient data to compute the statistic.
```

The closest I got to the value produced by the java program was when I used this formula https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35b.htm but i was still over 0.2 from the expected value.

I do not understand the squared brackets and when I tried to implement the formula I was 3 orders of magnitude from the desired value.

Is it possible to have the java documentation formula to be translated either to Ruby or some kind of mathematical notation that makes sense?

## first attempt

This is my Ruby translation that is by around 0.2 greater than the value produced by java program.

```
  def kurtosis
    return 0 if @values.length == 1
    cached_mean = mean
    n = @values.length.to_f

    rku = @values.sum { |x| (x - cached_mean)**4 }
    rkb = standard_deviation**4
    real_kurtosis = rku / rkb

    bk = (n * (n + 1)) / ((n - 1) * (n - 2) * (n - 3))
    ak = (3 * (n - 1)**2) / ((n - 2) * (n - 3))
    (bk * real_kurtosis) - ak
  end
```

Comment: You might do better looking at the source code for the Java class.

Comment: I ended up using another formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four slightly different definitions of the kurtosis:

[image]

The **excess** kurtosis is the difference between the kurtosis of a given distribution and the kurtosis of a normal distribution. The **bias** is the difference between the expected value and the true value of the parameter being estimated. A more complete explanation is found e.g. in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias_of_an_estimator.

You can only compare kurtosis values belonging to the same kurtosis version. The nist-website (https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35b.htm) explains the **biased** versions, the Java documentation (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math//javadocs/api-3.0/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/moment/Kurtosis.html) the **unbiased excess** kurtosis. Generally, both values differ in accordance with your results.